# Ionic 2 Camera makes app crash

Tags: ionic2

When i use the camera button that should launch the camera on my android device it gives me this error with chrome inspect:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/.Pic.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

I am clueless, can't find it anywere..

All help is appreciated!

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 5):

Passing in Width and Height solves the crashing issue for me.

```
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64:
      this.idImage = imageData;
      this.idImageSelected = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

got this solved updating `cordova platform` android to be 6.1.1 and then updating the camera plugin.

check your android cordova platform version:

`cordova platform ls`

if android is 6.0 < then you need to update it and add the updated version to your project, this should work:

`cordova platform update android`

but in my case it won't update the android platform version so I had to explicitly install 6.1.1

`cordova platform add android@6.1.1 --save`

then it updated to 6.1.1 and I then removed and added cordova camera plugin to my project:

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera --save`

and then

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save`

an up to date cordova-plugin-camera was then installed and I could see it in my config.xml

I've deployed my app to device again `ionic run android` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I do with this options : run well in Android device

```
 doCamera() {
      Camera.getPicture({
           destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
           saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
           mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      }).then((imageURI) => {
           this.changeImageString(imageURI);
      }, (err) => {
           console.log("Error: " + err);
      });

 }
```

see [enter link description here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_Camera)

Ionic Info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.38
Node Version: v6.8.1
```

Comment: I tried it, and other tutorials that should work but it still crashes. I'm starting to think it has nothing to do with the code..

Comment: this would never work the error happens before camera.getpicture resolve so you'll never have a chance to handle the imageURI like this.